# Fonts in Geany are bold after installing LibreOffice

Tags: fonts, libreoffice, geany

I've installed LibreOffice 7.1.1.2 64-bit on Windows 10 20H2 Pro and now the default Monospace font in Geany 1.37.1 is always bold (some other fonts are also affected).
Changing the Monospace in Geany from normal to bold (and back) doesn't make any difference.
What can I do to prevent Monospace and other fonts from being bold in Geany?
Restarting Windows doesn't help; also I didn't find any suggestions or solutions online.
This is the problem:
[image]

And this is how it should be:
[image]

Comment: If your image of how it should be is accurate, then it would seem your Geany was using a different font as "Monospace" before LibreOffice was installed. Specifically, the font in your "how it should be" image is "Courier New Regular".

Comment: No, I was always using Monospace. The second image comes from from my another computer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that default Monospace in Geany is not an actual font, it's just an alias.
On Windows 10 in Geany 1.37.1 Monospace (without LibreOffice installed) is actually a Courier New font, which fortunately wasn't bold.
Changing Monospace to Courier New was a workaround for me.
I still don't know why it happened; reinstalling and updating Geany and deleting it's folder from `%APPDATA%` didn't helped.